# Auto submit form when WordPress comment submitted

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have created one form to upload images for custom use

```
<form id="file-upload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="image-uploader-box" class="group">           
        <div id="forms" class="add-photo-fields">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            <input type="button" id="add-photo-button" class="add-photo-button" value="Add Photo"/>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Now it is working fine with uploading image and storing to proper place. But what I exactly want is auto submit above form when user submit WordPress comment. ( when user hit the submit comment button )

Can anyone help me for this? I am fine with jquery or php either way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the place to go: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ (jquery's submit function)
When uploading files you can post to an iframe: [How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe/168488#168488)

Comment: Please give me some idea how to do. I have read the docs you posted but one is complex for me to understand and other is asp so bumped.

Comment: Rather than fiddling on your own, you could use a plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload, they have an excellent documentation over here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Comment: Thanks for sharing let me try

Comment: But this is too much for my small need. It is not good idea to use too much code and script for one simple need.

Comment: Then you could very well use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356936/simple-jquery-file-upload-plugin-using-only-iframes

Comment: I appreciate your help but rather you are trying to help me with my code you are searching and sharing links with me. I need help with some example code and explanation.

Comment: No I am not. Just want to understand the logic and how to work with this. Also most of the code you share showing either AJAX upload or multiple upload rather I want one form auto submit on another form submission. Which I couldn't understand or not found in those code.